# why is my fileupload control not working on a live server but works perfectly on my machine?

Tags: asp.net

im trying to upload an image just about 500KB or less. As I said it works perfectly on my machine, but behaves totally weird on a live server. Something wrong with my config but I can't figure it out. I keep on getting this error "thumb image cannot be uploaded." pls help!

### my web config

```
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="150" maxRequestLength="307200" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="~/PropertyImages">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="307200" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/PropertyImages/thumbs">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="112640" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="307200"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

### my control

```
<asp:Label ID="Image1Label" runat="server" CssClass="inputLabels" />&nbsp;<asp:FileUpload ID="image1FileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="adminUpload" />
                                <asp:Button ID="upload1Button" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="upload1Button_Click" CssClass="adminButton" />
```

### my code behind file

```
protected void upload1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean fileOK = false;
        String path = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages/thumbs/");
        if (image1FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(image1FileUpload.FileName).ToLower();
            String[] allowedExtensions = { ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
            for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                {
                    fileOK = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fileOK)
        {
            try
            {
                int fileSize = image1FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (fileSize > 112640)
                {
                    statusLabel.Text = "thumb image size exceeded.";
                }
                else
                {                
                    image1FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + image1FileUpload.FileName);
                    statusLabel.Text = "thumb image uploaded!";
                    // update database with new property details
                    PropertyDetails pd = CatalogAccess.GetPropertyDetails(currentPropertyId);
                    CatalogAccess.UpdatePropertyThumbnailFrontImage(currentPropertyId, image1FileUpload.FileName);
                    // reload the page 
                    Response.Redirect("AdminPropertyDetails.aspx" +
                            "?DepartmentID=" + currentDepartmentId +
                            "&CategoryID=" + currentCategoryId +
                            "&PropertyID=" + currentPropertyId);

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusLabel.Text = "thumb image cannot be uploaded.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
        }


    }
```

Comment: what is the exception? most likely it could be a file/folder permission issue. check what the exception is. you are NOT logging your exceptions but instead just displaying a message to the user. LOG YOUR EXCEPTIONS!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you're passing the `image1FileUpload.FileName` to your `UpdatePropertyThumbnailFrontImage` method, I'm assuming that this method is trying to read the file from that path?

That won't work. The [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the path - or sometimes just the name - of the file **on the client**. Code on the server cannot read files on the client. It only works when you test it locally because the client and server are the same.

You either need to use the [`PostedFile` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the [`HttpPostedFile` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and use its [`InputStream` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SaveAs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or you need to call the [`SaveAs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [`FileUpload` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save the uploaded file somewhere on the server.

For example:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages/thumbs/");
string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image1FileUpload.FileName);
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, name);
image1FileUpload.SaveAs(path);

CatalogAccess.UpdatePropertyThumbnailFrontImage(currentPropertyId, path);
```